# Horizontal scrolling not working in tabBar of three20 project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, three20

I am using the three20 open source project by Joe Hewitt.

have the following code in a UITableViewController:

```
_tabBar1 = [[TTTabStrip alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 41)];
_tabBar1.tabItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                [[[TTTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"item1"] autorelease],
                [[[TTTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"item2"] autorelease],
                [[[TTTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"item3"] autorelease],
                [[[TTTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"item4"] autorelease],
                [[[TTTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"item5"] autorelease],
                [[[TTTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"item6"] autorelease],                   nil];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView= _tabBar1;
```

Everything seems to be working fine except that the TabBarStrip will not scroll horizontally?  Any idea why this is happening and any possible solutions?

Comment: are you building against 3.0?  i found a lot of UI elements break under 3.0. specifically when it relates to scrolling.  ( there is an issue with the MessageViewController as well)

Comment: even under 2.2.1 it does not horizontally scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was what i did wrong:

In project settings, under other linker flags, i did not add "all_load", i only added "ObjC".

Answer (score 0):

`TTTabStrip` is no longer available in the Three20 source code. You may want to migrate your code to the new `TTTabBar` class.

Do you know if the `TTTabStrip` view is meant to scroll horizontally? Having so many items in a tab strip seems like a user interface that's overly complicated for a device like the iPhone.